# Mysql Query: LEFT JOIN List all orders and "balance due" for a customer, if no orders, just list customer. 3 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have a customers table, orders table, and payments table.

From these I am trying to get one table that has for each record: customer#, order#, Balance due. But if a customer has no order then I just want to list the customer# with NULL values for the other fields.

Using a LEFT JOIN I was able to do this with just the customer# and order# but I cannot figure out how to get the balance due in there as well. I am fairly new to Mysql and tried to search the answer but was unable.

Here is what works for just the customer# and order#:

```
SELECT
    customers.cust_num,
    orders.order_id
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN orders ON customers.cust_num = orders.cust_num
```

But I am trying to incorporate "orders.invoice_amount - SUM(payments.amount) AS balance_due" as another column where the payments table is related to the orders table by a field called "order_id" in both.

Perhaps something like:
`SELECT orders.invoice_amount - SUM(payments.amount) AS balance_due FROM payments, orders WHERE payments.order_id = orders.order_id`

Any idea of how I could go about doing that or pointers in the right direction?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do an additional LEFT JOIN, but to a sub-query on payments grouped by order.  So, if it finds a record in the prequeried result, you are good to go.  Also, I changed to using table "aliases" for shorter readability, especially if table names get long, or you have to join multiple times to the same table in a query.

```
SELECT
      c.cust_num,
      coalesce( o.order_id, 0 ) as Order_ID,
      coalesce( o.invoice_amount, 0 ) as InvoiceAmount,
      coalesce( Prepaid.TotalPaid, 0 ) as TotalPaid,
      coalesce( o.invoice_amount - coalesce( PrePaid.TotalPaid, 0 ), 0) as BalanceDue
   FROM 
      customers c
         LEFT JOIN orders o 
            ON c.cust_num = o.cust_num
            LEFT JOIN
            ( select 
                    p.order_id,
                    sum( p.amount ) as totalPaid
                 from
                    payments p
                 group by
                    p.order_id ) as PrePaid
               on o.order_id = PrePaid.order_id
```

Comment: Worked awesome as a query (thx btw!)! Then I tried to make a view with it and found out that Mysql does not support SELECT statement containing a subquery in the FROM clause :( So I read that I could make two different views and combine in one but that would be a performance penalty. Do you know how I would do that here? Would it be wise?

Comment: @silent_john, obviously going against an entire database every time might be an issue, but how/what criteria would you want to limit it by... specific customers, those customers who had an order within the last year, ???  This might just be extra "where" criteria strategically in place with help of possible additional indexes.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like

```
SELECT
    customers.cust_num,
    orders.order_id, 
      orders.invoice_amount - SUM(payments.amount)
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN orders ON customers.cust_num = orders.cust_num
INNER JOIN payments P ON P..order_id = orders.order_id
group by cust_num,order_id,orders.invoice_amount
```